# How do I get to heroku error pages like on a local server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

After deploying my app to heroku i get application error. But i do not get stack trace and any other information in browser. Yeah i know i can use heroky -logs but they don't give me information at all.All Ready try to set up ENV=Development. Want to my error pages on heroku  will looks like [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPcIE.png]

Answer (score 1):

try this, you can keep track

```
heroku logs -t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch errors manually and show they at view

Errors catching in Ruby is perfomes via `begin`, `rescue`, `else`, `ensure` and `end`

And you are need not catch errors in each method of each controller - you just can add common handler for unhandled exceptions, [look here how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25219164/is-it-possible-to-catch-ruby-on-rails-error-pages-and-do-my-own-error-handling)

Answer (score 0):

On heroku your app runs in production mode. I beleive, the answer for this question should help: [Rails - error in production mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601484/rails-error-in-production-mode)

Answer (score 0):

To see development like errors on Heroku you have to run the app in development mode. Heroku sets two config variables `RACK_ENV` and `RAILS_ENV` to `production` by default when you deploy your app to heroku, you can see this in config vars under heroku app settings.

To run your app in development mode set `RACK_ENV` and `RAILS_ENV` to `development`.

You can do this through heroku toolbelt:

```
heroku config:set RACK_ENV=development --app app-name
heroku config:set RAILS_ENV=development --app app-name
```

Not to mention but you should set this back to `production` before giving it to your real users.